# Sylius create taxon - The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: sylius

When I go to the admin panel of Sirius and create category(taxon), and then delete it, and then re-create with the same name I get an error - The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
You can try on http://demo.sylius.org/, the same situation on local site.

Can somebody help? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a taxon it's not deleted in database. 
There is an column deleted_at which is null by default and if a taxon is deleted this field has a date.

If you want to undelete your taxon you must set this field to null.

Comment: thanks.
You mean that I have to create additional functionality just to do something as simple as taxon removing and Silius can not do it yourself?

Comment: If you update to the last version it has been fixed, but you might have lot of BC.